# how to select first two characters of textbox value

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

suppose I have two textboxes say textbox 1 and textbox 2...

textbox 1 is for company name.
textbox 2 is for company code or just a short name....

if I enter comapny name like "Mangalam mills pvt ltd" in textbox 1  than a short code of four letters  should be created in textbox 2 like MMPL or like MAMI...( all initial letters from textbox1 text)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVgu5.png)
pls help
thanks

I have tried to search on google but did not find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `String.Split` and `String.Concat`:

```
TextBox2.Text = 
    string.Concat(TextBox1.Text.Split().Select(t => t.First())).ToUpper(); // MMPL
```

If you want the first two characters of each "word" use:

```
TextBox2.Text = string.Concat(TextBox1.Text.Split()
    .Select(t => string.Concat(t.Take(2)))).ToUpper(); // MAMIPVLT
```

If you want the first two characters of the first two "words" use:

```
TextBox2.Text = string.Concat(TextBox1.Text.Split().Take(2)
    .Select(t => string.Concat(t.Take(2)))).ToUpper(); // MAMI
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you're asking for is relatively simple. You can just [`Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-7.0) on `space`, then take the first character of every substring, convert that character to upper case using `ToUpper()` and then concatenate that back to a string using either [`Join()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-7.0) or [`Concat()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.concat?view=net-7.0).

```cs
namespace MyProgram;

public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetShortName("Mangalam mills pvt ltd"));

    }

    public static string GetShortName(string companyName)
    {
        var namePartsInitials = companyName
            // we need to use RemoveEmptyEntries to avoid First() throwing an exception
            .Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(x => x.First().ToString().ToUpper()); // Call to Upper() here
        return string.Concat(namePartsInitials); // also possible to call ToUpper() here
        // or alternatively:
        // return string.Join(string.Empty, namePartsInitials);
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
MMPL
```

I am not sure what the purpose of this short name is, but obviously this name might not be unique and maybe (at least theoretically)  even consist of a single letter, so you might wanna think about that.

> Obviously your input would be the value of your `textbox 1` and you would need to set the return value of that function as the value for `textbox 2`